# Download a (.exe) file through vb or cmd

Tags: vb.net, download, cmd, exe

I need a way of downloading a program through either visual basic or cmd. I have tried these, but the file after it's downloaded is only about 600 bytes and doesn't work. I own this website and have ftp access, if I download it through ftp it's fine. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 by the way. These are the methods I've tried:

CMD through VB:

```
Dim MyCmd, Ws, Ret
Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
MyCmd = "cmd /c Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile  -WindowStyle Hidden (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://minecraftmapmakerstool.16mb.com/downloads/The_Map_Makers_Tool.exe','C:\Users\user\Desktop\The_Map_Makers_Tool.exe'); Start-Process C:\Users\user\Desktop\The_Map_Makers_Tool.exe;"
Ret = Ws.run(MyCmd, 0, True)
```

VB:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://minecraftmapmakerstool.16mb.com/downloads/The_Map_Makers_Tool.exe", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\The_Map_Makers_Tool.exe")
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: also check this
https://www.greyhathacker.net/?p=500

Comment: What are the contents of the file when viewed in Notepad? 600 bytes could be e.g.a 404 response.

Comment: .. note the [documentation for DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says "The DownloadFile method does not send optional HTTP headers. **Some servers may return 500 (Internal Server Error) if the optional user agent header is missing.** To send optional headers, you must construct a request using the WebClient class." - so the 600 bytes could be the 500 response.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is no built in tool in Windows that would do that for you. But there are plenty free programs on the web, that you can install and then call from your batch script. Here is one of them: [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl)

Here is a basic example of how to use it (using your link)

@echo Off
Title
Pause
CD C:\Users\Jah\desktop
curl http://www.jah.com/ofac/downloads/t11sdn.pdf > download.pdf
This would download and save the file from the URL you have provided to download.pdf

Another possible alternative would be [WGET](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).